# Django rest_framework / validate PATCH request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'm new in Django Rest framework. I'm trying to do some test task (simple RestAPI service) but it failed.

I've created model `Order`, serializer `OrderSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer)`, and `OrderViewSet(ModelViewSet)`. (nothing special, use code from tutorial).
I tested GET/POST and it works good.
But PATCH request works strange. I do PATCH with different fields in payload (which don't exist in the model) and there is no error in response, response code is 200 always.

`models.py`

```
class EOrderStatus(Enum):
    Unknown = 0
    Created = 1
    Paid = 2
    Failed = 3

class Order(models.Model):
    _status = models.SmallIntegerField(default=EOrderStatus.Created.value)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now, editable=False)
    pay_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

*serializers.py*

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id', '_status', 'create_date', 'pay_date', 'description']
```

`views.py`

```
class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
```

```
PATCH /api/orders/1, status code 200
{
    "dessssss": "aaa",
    "statttttt": "11"
}
```

My question is: why status code is 200? I supposed that I must to receive error something like "invalid fields ...". Do I need to write patch-validator for each `model/serializer`?

And 2nd question: model Order contains enum-field `_status`. What is the best way don't use `_status` in request/response, but use property `status` instead? (`string type, EOrderStatus.Created.name`)

Comment: When sending a request, if you send fields that are not present in the serializer, DRF will simply not look at them as they are irrelevant. I recommend you also look at the differences between PATCH and PUT requests.

Comment: I didn't find this feature in put/patch request. I guess this is DRF feature. But maybe it's configurable? I used Flask before and it validates fields in PATCH request by default.